# Use Swift subscripts in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2

I have declared a subscript in swift and wanted to know if it is possible to use a swift subscript in objective-c ? Because I have made my class inherit from NSObject and made the subscript public. But I still cannot have access to it. 
I am asking this question based on this line in the Apple's "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" :

[image]

How to make the subscript compatible to Objective-C or is Swift subscripts is a specific swift feature ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is absolutely possible, see:

```
class MyArray : NSObject {
    var data: [Int] = [0, 1, 2]

    subscript (index: Int) -> NSNumber {
        return data[index]
    }
}
```

Obj-C:

```
MyArray *array = [[MyArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *value = array[0];
```

There are some limitations though. You cannot return a primitive value (`Int`), you have to return an Obj-C object, e.g. `NSNumber`.

Comment: I didn't know this, it surprises me that this works.

Comment: Super. I did not knew about the limitations. I was returning Any from my subscript. This works